# Android Data Binding Cannot Find Package

Tags: android, android-databinding

I just updated my Android Studio to 3.2.1. Now, my data binding doesn't work at all. I have a package where I store my data classes e.g Profile. In the data binding generated class, where there is an import `import tinkshare.myapp.models.Profile;`, it shows an error stating `error: package Profile does not exist`, yet in other pieces of code that I've written, I import the same with no issue.

Comment: which annotation processor you're using for **data binding**?

Comment: None. Should I be using any?

Comment: Try using this compiler `kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:$gradle_version"`, gradle version is same version you're using for gradle plugin, **annotationProcessor** instead of **kapt** for java.

Comment: Nothing, same issue.

Comment: Does **Rebuild project** solved this issue?

Comment: No, it does not. Still got the same errors even after cleaning project.